# Powershell exit does not work

Tags: powershell, exception

I am writing a script which checks for a registry value and and exits if is 0. (It will proceed if the value is 1.)

```
  if ((Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ICT\LoginScript).proceed -eq 0) {

        $form.close()
        exit             

        }
```

When I run the script with the reg value at 0, it fails to exit and throws an exception instead:

```
System.Management.Automation.ExitException: System error.
   at System.Management.Automation.FlowControlNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.ParseTreeNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
  ...
```

The script is using windows forms - not sure if that is relevant?

EDIT:

I have reduced the script to the following to  test:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$Form.Add_Shown({ $Form.Activate(); start-sleep -s 3; exit; $form.close() })
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

And this still gives the error. If I run the `start-sleep -s 3; exit` code on a non-windows form it works fine, so it looks like the issue is tied in with Windows Forms.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: The Get-ItemProperty seems to be irrelevant - that's correct in my tests (although it will throw if the path is not found). I think the issue is with $form.close(). You'll need to show more (how $form is declared, etc.).

Comment: Could you please post the complete script that can reproduce the issue? Create a minimal example that still reproduces the problem and post it here.
Also could you please try to execute the whole thing via command line (i.e. not from a script file) and report if this error still exists.

Comment: Please see edit above - error seems to be with Windows forms?

Comment: I want the script to terminate if the test fails. At the moment it will close the GUI window, but continue running the rest of the script anyway. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `exit` has the same effect as `Exit-PSSession`. Looking at the stacktrace, I think the code is attempting to end the interactive session from a different thread, and that's why it fails.

Are you just trying to end the script? You could try `[Runspace]::DefaultRunspace.CloseAsync()` instead.

Comment: I tried this, but got a different error saying the pipeline had stopped. Also, Exit-PSSession doesn't seem to end the script either? The command doesn't error, but it just continues running after Exit-PSSession has executed.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to make use of functions and/or a Boolean value. If the test fails, just set a Boolean value somewhere to indicate that you don't want the rest of the script to be executed. So for example, before the block of code you don't want to be executed if the test fails, just put something like `if ($failed) { exit }`

Comment: Yep - with hindsight I think this is going to be the best way to go. Thanks for your help, George.