# System.Management.Automation.ExitException: System error in Powershell Studio

Tags: powershell, powershell-studio

I made a script in Powershell: when I import the CSV file I want to check if the users already exists. This is the script:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell

$adusers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "DC=KOJ,DC=NL" -Filter * |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

$UserList = Import-Csv -Path $txt_csv.Text -Delimiter ";" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty UPN

$exist = Compare-Object $adusers $Userlist -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

$flag = 0

foreach ($user in $exist) {         
    $flag = 1           
    $a = $wshell.Popup("$user exist make unique!", 0, "stop", 0x1)          
    Write-Host $user "already exists"           
}

if ($flag -eq 1) {          
    $form.Close()
    exit
}
```

When the user already exists I get the following error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Management.Automation.ExitException: System error.
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
   at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeWithPipe>b__8()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(Object dollarUnder, Object dollarThis, Object[] args)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , EventArgs )
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

(FYI I already have read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327003/powershell-exit-does-not-work))

I don't know which condition I have to use in the `if` statement.

I also tried with `[environment]::exit(0)` but then my PowerShell environment closes and I don't want that.

Can you guys help me with a solution?

Kind regards.

Comment: Hi, what is `$form`? Why do you think you need `exit` here?

Comment: The $form is the main gui interface. When an user exist I want to stop the script and close the GUI form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `return` and everything works!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't `$form.Close()` enough to close the form?

Comment: Only the GUI will close, but the script is still running then. With **return** the script stops and the GUI is still open.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I try to exit the script app.
I solved it with this:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Exit()
```

Comment: Especially if you use [`[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314514/whats-the-difference-between-application-run-and-form-showdialog "What's the difference between Application.Run() and Form.ShowDialog()?") ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run "Application.Run Method"))